# How to show star ratings in css when rating is known?

Tags: php, html, css

I am working on a website in which to show star ratings when rating in known. Below is the JSON object having all necessary information:

```
"item_ratings": [{
    "rating_id": 26,
    "item_id": 333,
    "booking_id": 60,
    "owner_id": null,
    "renter_id": 38,
    "rating": 5,
    "rating_type": "item",
    "created_at": "2018-07-04 10:28:55",
    "updated_at": "2018-07-04 10:28:55",
}, {
    "rating_id": 15,
    "item_id": 333,
    "booking_id": null,
    "owner_id": null,
    "renter_id": 38,
    "rating": 4,
    "rating_type": "item",
    "created_at": "2018-01-17 10:16:58",
    "updated_at": "2018-01-17 10:16:58",
}]
```

The code which I am using in php in order to pull the rating is:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($data['item']->item_details->item_ratings); $i++) 
{
echo '<p class="renter_review_ratings">'.strtolower($data['item']->item_details->item_ratings[$i]->rating).'</p>';
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the php code above so that **when it is 4, it should display 4 stars, when it is 3 it should display 3 stars and vice versa.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you use [FontAwesome 5](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/getting-started?using=web-fonts-with-css) and your rating is out of 5 stars, the following code should work.

```
for ($j = 0; $j < count($data['item']->item_details->item_ratings); $j++) {
  $rating = $data['item']->item_details->item_ratings[$j]->rating;
  for($i = 1;$i <= 5;$i++) {
    if ($rating >= $i) {
      echo "<i class='fas fa-star'></i>";
    } else {
      echo "<i class='far fa-star'></i>";
    }
  }
}
```

What is happening here is that, we have the first `for` loop that gets all the ratings. It then has another nested `for` loop that loops exactly 5 times. Each time it looks it uses an `if` statement to determine whether to show a full star or an empty star using the FontAwesome library.

Comment: The current php code have many echo statements which I haven't shown.

Comment: Should be able to replace your current PHP code with mine and its results should be the same however, it will use FontAwesome rather than plain text. However, you must have the FontAwesome library on your website. Go to FontAwesome's website (linked in answer) and use their CDN to begin with to see it work in action.

Comment: Just add your echo's after the declaration of the `$rating` variable and before the loop.

Comment: The main echo statement is in the 3rd last line.

Comment: Sorry I send you the wrong fiddle. Here is the correct fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pr25j3f1/2/

Comment: Are you around ?

Comment: @john having a look now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178823/discussion-between-lachie-and-john).

Answer (score 1):

As per your json you can do like this :-

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($data['item']->item_details->item_ratings); $i++) 
{
    for($j = 0; $j < 5; $j++)
    {
        if($j <= $data['item']->item_details->item_ratings[$i]->rating) {
            // Star code
        } else {
            // No star code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What should I mention inside the // star code comment ?

Comment: You can use `FontAwesome` icon or image